# docker-nginx with docker-gen doesnt catch any of the declared subdomain

Tags: nginx, proxy

I setted up docker-nginx with docker-gen in a docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    labels:
        com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy: "true"
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro

  nginx-gen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    command: -notify-sighup nginx -watch -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    container_name: nginx-gen
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl:ro

  nginx-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-letsencrypt
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ${NGINX_FILES_PATH}/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    environment:
      NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER: "nginx-gen"
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: "nginx"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

everything works fine, I do have a default.conf folder generated, depending on my others containers, here it is:

```
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Proto, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# scheme used to connect to this server
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto {
  default $http_x_forwarded_proto;
  ''      $scheme;
}
# If we receive X-Forwarded-Port, pass it through; otherwise, pass along the
# server port the client connected to
map $http_x_forwarded_port $proxy_x_forwarded_port {
  default $http_x_forwarded_port;
  ''      $server_port;
}
# If we receive Upgrade, set Connection to "upgrade"; otherwise, delete any
# Connection header that may have been passed to this server
map $http_upgrade $proxy_connection {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}
# Apply fix for very long server names
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
# Default dhparam
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam.pem;
# Set appropriate X-Forwarded-Ssl header
map $scheme $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl {
  default off;
  https on;
}
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
log_format vhost '$host $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                 '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                 '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
access_log off;
# HTTP 1.1 support
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $proxy_connection;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
# Mitigate httpoxy attack (see README for details)
proxy_set_header Proxy "";
server {
    server_name _; # This is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.
    listen 80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    return 503;
}
# bnbkeeper.thibautduchene.fr
upstream bnbkeeper.thibautduchene.fr {
                ## Can be connect with "nginx-proxy" network
            # bnbkeeper
            server 172.20.0.12:8080;
}
server {
    server_name bnbkeeper.thibautduchene.fr;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://bnbkeeper.thibautduchene.fr;
    }
}
# gags.thibautduchene.fr
upstream gags.thibautduchene.fr {
                ## Can be connect with "nginx-proxy" network
            # gogs
            server 172.20.0.7:3000;
}
server {
    server_name gags.thibautduchene.fr;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://gags.thibautduchene.fr;
    }
}
# portainer.thibautduchene.fr
upstream portainer.thibautduchene.fr {
                ## Can be connect with "nginx-proxy" network
            # portainer
            server 172.20.0.9:9000;
}
server {
    server_name portainer.thibautduchene.fr;
    listen 80 ;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log vhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://portainer.thibautduchene.fr;
    }
}
```

however, when I reach any of these proxied address, the server does'nt exist and nginx doesnt even catch the request...

It looks like nginx is not even aware of my subdomain.

Comment: What do you mean by `the server doesn't exist` what errors do you get?

Comment: Nginx is not even notified if for example I enter portainer.thibautduchene.fr, it feels like I’m missing enablewebsite somewhere in the config.

Comment: can you manually reload going inside the nginx container and see if everything works?

Comment: You mean docker exec -it nginx sh; and restart nginx inside the container or just a docker restart nginx

Comment: Cause I have no idea what the cmd would be inside the container

Comment: inside the container run `nginx -s reload`

Comment: Got a message saying signal process started reloading portaient.thibautduchene.fr still nothing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154663/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-duduche).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for those that are as silly as me, don't forget to add the subdomain to your provider, nginx doe'st yet handle it by itself..